Correct way of centering and standardizing data in polynomial regression
I want to build a regression model using lasso regression. My understanding is that I should first scale and center my data (as asked here for example: Need for centering and standardizing data in regression).
However, I want to include interaction and quadratic terms of my measured data in the model (so if my data includes A and B, I also want to include A^2, A*B, and B^2 as predictors in my model.
My question is whether to calculate the interaction and quadratic terms first (so build X first) and then standardize each column independently, or to standardize A and B first and then build X from those standardized values.
For a normal least squares regression, it doesn't make a difference because polynomial regression models are invariant under linear transformation if and only if the polynomial is "hierarchically
well-formulated". Thus, the predictions made by models using either approach would be the same (as they would be for unstandardized data). But the value and sign of each coefficient could be different (in fact, the value will almost certainly be different), and since the Lasso regularizes the size of the coefficients, it should come to different conclusions.
I couldn't find a conclusive answer as to which order of operation is better. On the one hand, standardizing second after building X would ensure that all predictors have the same scale and are properly centered, which makes intuitive sense. But on the other hand, you lose the mathematical connection between the terms, where (A^2)_scaled wouldn't be the square of A_scaled. Scaling first is also the approach I've seen in some statistics software (though for ordinary least squares regression, where it doesn't matter), and since lasso regressions are not necessarily "hierarchically well formulated", I'm not sure it's valid.
I would appreciate any advice or explanation as to why one way or the other is better/correct. Ideally with some references.

I would add the interactions first (same as for quadratic/cubic variables) and then perform normalization (in general normalization will be towards the end). The reasoning is that you want each variable to have a similar scale for LASSO/RIDGE/etc. to work properly, and the scale of an interaction on normalized variables might have different ranges. Losing the "mathematical connection" is not really an issue, you aren't going to interpret the results anyway (mostly).

If you want to include interaction terms in your Lasso model (with polynomials a type of interaction term), you should consider hierarchical group-Lasso regularization, outlined in Example 4.3 of Statistical Learning with Sparsity, published by Lim and Hastie in "Learning Interactions via Hierarchical Group-Lasso
Regularization," Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics 24: 627–654 (2015), and implemented in the R glinternet package.
You don't have to scale individual predictors before Lasso; you can instead penalize their coefficients differently to account for their scales, as allowed for by the penalty.factor argument to the glmnet() function in the basic R glmnet package. That principle can be extended to a group Lasso, in which an interaction and all its associated individual terms are included or excluded as a group. That has the advantage of ensuring strong hierarchy for the interaction (any included interaction term also has all of its individual terms included), as is typically best practice.
Then each group can have its own penalty factor that takes into account the scales of the included predictors. Appendix A2 of Lim and Hastie shows how to scale groups of predictors "so that if the signal were pure noise, then all the groups are equally likely to be nonzero." If the design matrix for the variables in group i is $X_i$, then normalizing each $X_i$ to have Frobenius norm $\left(\sqrt{\text{trace}(X_i^T X_i)}\right)$ of 1 is the equivalent of pre-scaling an individual variable in Lasso, and all group penalty factors can be set to 1.
In the glinternet() implementation, you only provide the individual predictors and then either specify the interactions to consider or allow the function to identify interactions. From the manual page: "The continuous features are standardized to have unit norm and mean zero before computing the lambda sequence and fitting. The returned coefficients are unstandardized. Categorical variables are not standardized."
Do ask yourself, however, whether a polynomial fit is the best way to capture a nonlinear association between your predictor and outcome. Regression splines often work better.
In response to comment
I'm not aware of a glinternet implementation in Python, but for a situation like yours in which you evidently have just a few pre-specified interactions to evaluate you don't need that package's ability to evaluate a large number of interactions quickly. You can simply use group Lasso (see this Stack Overflow page for Python implementations) with a group for all the terms involved in the interaction (all of A, B, and AB in your example) along with the individual terms (for A and B in your example).
That way, if Lasso keeps the interaction in the model, you will at least have the coefficients for both of A and B returned from the interaction group. That maintains strict hierarchy. If an individual term for either of A or B is also kept in the model, use the sum of the individual-term coefficient along with the corresponding coefficient from the interaction group.
In terms of when to do the centering and scaling continuous predictors, do that first before calculating the interactions. That's how glinternet proceeds.
That pre-scaling doesn't really "lose the mathematical connection between the terms" in this context. Consider a continuous predictor $x$ and its square. If you first center $x$ around its mean $\bar x$ you get:
$$(x-\bar x)^2=  x^2 - 2x \bar x + \bar x^2.$$
That's just the $x^2$ that you are interested in along with terms involving the constant $\bar x$ that simply change the intercept ($\bar x^2$) or the coefficient for the linear $x$ term ($-2x \bar x$).
With individual terms in the interaction already centered and scaled and included as candidates for Lasso, you just need to normalize the design matrix for the group that includes them along with their interaction. Again, calculate the interaction term after the individual predictors are centered and scaled.
The proper scaling that allows all individual terms and groups to have the same penalty in Lasso is to have the Frobenius norm of the corresponding (group) design matrices to equal 1. For an individual predictor that's been centered, that just the variance. For the matrix including a group as for an interaction, it's the square root of the sums of the squares of its individual elements. Normalize that group design matrix accordingly in the group Lasso.

Thank you. Not the straight forward answer I was hoping for but thanks for the insight. Do you know if there is also a python library that does that? I've done the everything in python with scikit-learn so it would be nice if I could continue with that. Also thanks for mentioning Regression splines, I think that a polynomial regression is good enough for my case but I'll look into it.

@Scratched I added a bit to the answer to address implementation. It sounds like, for your application, you can use a Python implementation of group Lasso that includes both the individual predictors and the group including the individual predictors and their interaction. Check the documentation for the group Lasso that you use; it might perform the necessary scaling of the group design matrix for you. If not, the addition to the answer shows how to do it.
